# SQL Correlated Subquery: Is "Group By" needed?

Tags: sql

I am learning SQL. I understand the below code is finding the max list_price for each category_id.

However, is there a need for "Group by" in the last line? I have come across similar correlated subquery but they don't use a "Group by" to find the max XXX for each YYY.

Thank you

```
SELECT
    product_name
FROM
    production.products p1
WHERE
    list_price IN (
        SELECT
            MAX (p2.list_price)
        FROM
            production.products p2
        WHERE
            p2.category_id = p1.category_id
        GROUP BY
            p2.category_id
    );
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms .

Comment: The GROUP BY makes no difference, the subquery will still return only one value (the MAX value for the category p1.category_id.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort answer: No. "Group by" in SQL Correlated Subquery is not needed.

Long answer: Actually you can find it by yourself if you use "Explain Plan" on your query. If your query don't have many joins then the difference is not noticeable but in the case you have multiple joins then it's better not to use group by. Although if your subquery's data are grouped then the Cardinality of your main query is going to be much lower resulting in less joins between your main query and your subquery. So we come to the conclusion that the choice is up to you and how complicated your query is.

Comment: But he is "joining" the outer table `p1` with the inner `p2` in there where `p2.category_id = p1.category_id` on `category_id`